# laravel memcached as the CACHE_DRIVER doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, laravel, caching, memcached, lumen

I have memcached selected as my cache driver. However , ran into a weird issue.

Once I am doing:

```
Cache::put('name','John',15);
```

In the very next line if I give

```
var_dump(Cache::get('name'))
```

it shows me :

```
bool(false)
```

Couldn't understand what's going wrong here. I have memcached running on port 11211 on my localhost which I can telnet.

Also **phpinfo()** shows php-memcached library is installed.

My config/cache.php file reads:

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'memcached'),
 'stores' => [

    'apc' => [
        'driver' => 'apc',
    ],

    'array' => [
        'driver' => 'array',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table'  => env('CACHE_DATABASE_TABLE', 'cache'),
        'connection' => env('CACHE_DATABASE_CONNECTION', null),
    ],

    'file' => [
        'driver' => 'file',
        'path'   => storage_path('framework/cache'),
    ],

    'memcached' => [
        'driver'  => 'memcached',
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'), 'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211), 'weight' => 100,
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => env('CACHE_REDIS_CONNECTION', 'default'),
    ],

],
'prefix' => env('CACHE_PREFIX', 'laravel'),
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. The method to set a value in the cache is `put()`, but you used `get()` twice. Try this:

```
Cache::put('name','John',15);
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the question itself. I am using put only, not get.

Answer (score 0):

i spent 3 hours figuring out why my  code was not working and can’t get the data from the cache and finally i figured out why :

`Cache::put('name','John',15);`

and when you do that You put that on the Cache for Only 15s or maybe 15ms depends on your configuration on the code.

You have to also check if you have permission on the storage Folder :

`sudo CHOWN -R www:data:www:data storage`

You can verify that you inserted the data on cache  manually and you will see that you already cached that data but the expire date ttl is expired.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Finally after an entire day of Googling , I found the solution.

It seems I had to add the following line to **bootstrap/app.php** :

```
$app->configure('cache');
```

Also , please note that if you are running your application inside a VM/docker container , you need to provide the Host ip .

Comment: I'm in same situation my application is on heroku. When I try following 

Cache::put('name','John',15);
Cache::get('name') it displays => John 
but as soon as I comment

//Cache::put('name','John',15);
Cache::get('name') display nothing

Please let me know if any idea

Config:

'memcached' => [
        'driver' => 'memcached',
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                'weight' => 100,
            ],
        ],
    ],

Comment: I've tried your solution but it just breaks the website, here is a link : https://buynow.liqstage.co.za/